# How to make a textformfield circular in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a circular textformfield, but the text ends up leaving the circle, I wanted it to stay inside the circle but it ends up leaving

[image: imagem]

```
Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.amber,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
   child:TextFormField(
       expands: true,
       maxLines: null,
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
       keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
        filled: false,
        ),
   );
),
```

Comment: you should limit the max line. for example 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping text inside a circle (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974526/wrapping-text-inside-a-circle-flutter)

Comment: fyi, this feature request is still open on flutter's own github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49878

Comment: It ended up not working, I looked at the links and tried to do it in a similar way but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `Padding` and setting expand: true to fill container

```
Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150), color: Colors.amber),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
    child: TextFormField(
      expands: true,
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the TextFormField with an ClipRRect

```
Container(
                            height: 300,
                            width: 300,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                            child:ClipRRect(
                              child: TextFormField(
                                expands: true,
                                maxLines: null,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                                  filled: false,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
```

)             )

Comment: It ended up not working

Answer (score 0):

**Just wrap TextFormField with Container and give border radius to Container and apply InputBorder.none in decoration of TextFormFiels**

Ex :-

Container(

```
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 239, 209, 1),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter a number", border: InputBorder.none),
    ),
```

),